# Running a .net core windows service with admin privileges

Tags: c#, windows-services, topshelf

I have created a windows service using **.net core** and **Topshelf**.

I am not able to access the **com objects** when I run as a service whereas when I run the exe from command prompt with admin access, It's working as expected.

Could you please help. Thanks

Comment: Because your code needs admin right and that's by it working when you give admin access.. add code what you want to do with service/related code?

Comment: I'm creating Emails by accessing Outlook Interop from the services.

Comment: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office): "Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services)". That same notice has existed, in one form or another, in the Microsoft documentation, for close to two *decades*, IIRC.

Comment: Is your service running with admin privileges? Change the service "Log On" details to admin account

Comment: @ManishM - doesn't matter if they're running as admin or not. They're trying to use Outlook COM. Which isn't supported here, for the many reasons given in the link I provided above.